# sharedScheduler is deprecated?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, deprecated

So, I want to create a slow motion effect, and I am using this method:

```
[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] setTimeScale:0.5];
```

However, sharedScheduler is deprecated.

What is the equivalent method of creating a slow motion effect?

All answers and advice are appreciated!

Comment: look in ccDeprecated.m for alternatives. I suppose it's now available via CcDirector

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [CCDirector scheduler].

> CCActionManager, CCScheduler, CCTouchDispathcer (iOS) and
>   CCEventDispatcher (Mac) are NO LONGER singletons. Instead, they are
>   properties of CCDirector.

Link to documentation:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:migrate_to_v2.0

--

If I understand what you mean by slow motion effect correctly, you can also use actions as follows (am dry coding here so might require cleanup):

```
CCNode *obj = //some object;

[obj runAction:[CCSequence actions:
   [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.5],
   [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(YOURFUNCTION)],nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try replacing:**

`[[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] setTimeScale:0.5];`

**with:**

`[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] scheduler] setTimeScale:0.5];`